# Why the bottom property is not working in the nested div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following example, that I do not understand how does exactly work:

```css
* {
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}
body {
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 
}
h2 {
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:lighter;
 padding:0 0px 8px 0;
}
#container {
 width:980px;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:100px; 
}

.example {
 width:270px;
 height:270px;
 float:left;  
 margin-right:60px; 
}
#example3 {
 margin-right:0px; 
}


#example3 .grandparent {
 width:250px;
 height:250px;
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
 position:relative;
}

#example3 .parent {
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 background-color:#999999;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
}
#example3 .child {
 width:70px;
 height:70px;
 background-color:#666666;
 position:relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CSS Demo - Child DIVs positioned relative to parent</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    
    <div id="example3" class="example">
      <div class="grandparent">Grandparent
          <div class="parent">Parent
            <div class="child">Child</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why the property bottom is not working? But when I set for example `top: 50%`, then the property is accepted.

What happen, when I have nested div's with different position property?

Answer (score 0):

Change `position:relative` for `.child` to `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0):

Bottom property is not working in the nested div because of you are using bottom property with `position:relative;`. this will be work with `position:absolute;`.

```
#example3 .child {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#666666;
    position:relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```